# Sidebar overflow-y only triggered when screen is too small to view entire side bar

Tags: html, css, overflow

Im trying to implement a sidebar like [THIS SITE](https://smarkets.com/about/status/) (the black sidebar on the left, make your browser window small to trigger it). The `overflow-y:scroll;` only seems to work when there is not enough browser space to view the entire length of the sidenav.

Ive tried making a side nav and setting it `overflow-y:scroll;` but if i do this it displays the scrollbar constantly whether needed or not so you end up with it like this image below..

Any idea how to implement this so it acts like the site above ? - ive made a jsfiddle of the problem here http://jsfiddle.net/zRvRQ/1/

There is also a screencast of the example site here - if you cant get it to load - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fI7SFCUnq98&feature=youtu.be

[image: scroll bar]

Comment: did u try `overflow-y:auto`

Comment: Hm. Can't open the site above... But i'll try a solution, hope you mean something like that

Comment: @dTDesign - Ive updated the link see if that works better you now

Comment: @sam: I can't load this URL... Doesn't matter which browser, also can't open it with the mobile...

Comment: Is this question active? When yes, i'll try something

Answer (score 1):

I just watched your [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fI7SFCUnq98&feature=youtu.be).
First of all, your side nav should be `fixed`, so it don't scroll with the content.
Next the `overflow` must be `auto`. That means, the scrollbar only appears, when the list need to scroll.
I create a small example for you:
[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jzimC)

Hope now i'm on the right track.

PS: If you want also a custom scrollbar for your sidenav, take a look to [this article](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

Comment: Thanks, but the only problem with specifying an absolute height, is that you dont know what size the users browser is,

Comment: @sam: Updated both of the Demo's. I added a body-tag, then the `ul` will take the height of the body...

Comment: Thanks - the second example is more like it - ive also made a screen cast of the example site if your interested - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fI7SFCUnq98&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @sam: Ah dammit. Youtube is locked by the proxy of my company :/ Is there no other site's with your side nav?

Comment: Im sure there are, but i couldnt think of any off the top of my head, ive uploaded the vid to Dropbox here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/mqvrh0g6b262cm4/sidenav.mov - can you use that at work ?

Comment: No :( Also dropbox is blocked. But i'll watch the video on my mobile. hang on